# load failed for ‘qdap’ on Mac Sierra in Rstudio

Tags: java, macos, rstudio, rjava, qdap

I'm trying to run app in Rstudio using "shiny" package, but I get this the error quoted below. I read the posts here, so I guess there must be a problem with rJava? I have downloaded the rJava package in Rstudio. The version of java on my Mac is java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode). I'm a new user so will greatly appreciate any feedback. Thank you in advance.
Here is the error in Rstudio that I get when I try to run app:

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7074
Loading required package: NLP
Loading required package: qdapDictionaries
Loading required package: qdapRegex

Attaching package: ‘qdapRegex’

The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:

```
validate
```

Loading required package: qdapTools
Loading required package: RColorBrewer
JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'openNLPdata', details:
  call: .jinit()
  error: JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1

Warning: Error in : package or namespace load failed for ‘qdap’
Stack trace (innermost first):
    40: library
     1: runApp
Error : package or namespace load failed for ‘qdap’
JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'openNLPdata', details:
  call: .jinit()
  error: JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1

Warning: Error in : package or namespace load failed for ‘qdap’
Stack trace (innermost first):
    40: library
     1: runApp
Error : package or namespace load failed for ‘qdap’
JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'openNLPdata', details:
  call: .jinit()
  error: JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1

Warning: Error in : package or namespace load failed for ‘qdap’
Stack trace (innermost first):
    40: library
     1: runApp
Error : package or namespace load failed for ‘qdap’